# Is it possible to find a list of all questions in which I have written a comment?

Tags: support

I have written a comment to a question a few months ago and I remember one user had an interesting answer (also as a comment) but I cannot find that question any more. Is there a way to have a list of all questions in which I have posted a comment?

I have found nothing about this in my profile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a list of all the comments you've posted on your profile:

Go to [Activity > Comments](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/29020/giorgio?tab=activity&sort=comments)

But it doesn't distinguish between comments on questions and comments on answers.

Comment: Found it, thanks. I was looking at the options in the main page while the Activity link is in the small window that opens when hovering on my user name. Many thanks!